# How to fix this kind of error Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a simple ListView with GetX but it gives me this error when starting the app "**Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'map' was called on null.**", I'm new to flutter and dart, that's why I'm starting with the "easiest" and for work reasons they ask me to add GetX

Home

```
class HomePage extends GetView<HomeController> {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //  final homeController = Get.put(HomeController());
    var title = "HomePage";
    return Scaffold(
      
      body: Obx(() {
        HomeController controller = Get.find<HomeController>();
        return controller.regionList.isEmpty
            ? const Center(
                child: Text('No hay regiones'),
              )
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: controller.regionList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
                        title: Text(
                      controller.regionList[index].name,
                    )));
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Controller

```
class HomeController extends GetxController {

  //late Regiones model;
  var regionList = <Regiones>[].obs;

  Future<List<Regiones>> getRegiones() async {
    var response = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/response.json');
    var results = (jsonDecode(response)['regions'] ?? []) as List;
    return results.map((x) => Regiones.fromJson(x)).toList();
    //return Regiones.fromJson(jsonDecode(response));
  }
  //Json['regions'] == null ? Null :

  @override
  Future<void> onInit() async {
    // TODO: implement onInit
    super.onInit();
    regionList.assignAll(await getRegiones());
  }
}
```

Json

```
{
  "name": "Chile",
  "regions": [
    {
      "name": "Arica y Parinacota",
      "romanNumber": "XV",
      "number": "15",
      "abbreviation": "AP",
      "communes": [
        { "name": "Arica", "identifier": "XV-1" },
        { "name": "Camarones", "identifier": "XV-2" },
        { "name": "General Lagos", "identifier": "XV-3" },
        { "name": "Putre", "identifier": "XV-4" }
      ]
    },
    {
...
```

Model

```
Regiones regionesFromJson(String str) => Regiones.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String regionesToJson(Regiones data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Regiones {
  Regiones({
    required this.name,
    required this.regions,
  });

  String name;
  List<Region> regions;

  factory Regiones.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Regiones(
        name: json["name"],
        regions:
            List<Region>.from(json["regions"].map((x) => Region.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "regions": List<dynamic>.from(regions.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Region {
  Region({
    required this.name,
    required this.romanNumber,
    required this.number,
    required this.abbreviation,
    required this.communes,
  });

  String? name;
  String? romanNumber;
  String? number;
  String? abbreviation;
  List<Commune> communes;

  factory Region.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Region(
        name: json["name"],
        romanNumber: json["romanNumber"],
        number: json["number"],
        abbreviation: json["abbreviation"],
        communes: List<Commune>.from(
            json["communes"].map((x) => Commune.fromJson(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "romanNumber": romanNumber,
        "number": number,
        "abbreviation": abbreviation,
        "communes": List<dynamic>.from(communes.map((x) => x.toJson())),
      };
}

class Commune {
  Commune({
    required this.name,
    required this.identifier,
  });

  String name;
  String identifier;

  factory Commune.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Commune(
        name: json["name"],
        identifier: json["identifier"] ?? '',
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "name": name,
        "identifier": identifier,
      };
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `['regions']` in two place:

**1:**

```
var results = (jsonDecode(response)['regions'] ?? []) as List;
```

**2:** inside `Regiones.fromJson`
so in your HomeController instead of this:

```
return results.map((x) => Regiones.fromJson(x)).toList();
```

try this:

```
return results.map((x) => Region.fromJson(x)).toList();
```

and then make your getRegiones return Future<List> like this:

```
Future<List<Regione>> getRegiones() async {
...
}
```

Comment: In the home it marks an error in this line: `controller.regionList[index].name,`
: Error: The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String' because 'String?' is nullable and 'String' isn't.

Comment: change this  Text(
                      controller.regionList[index].name,
                    ) to Text(
                      controller.regionList[index].name ??" ",
                    )